How to open default video player in Unity App on Oculus Quest 2 (Android)
I don’t understand how to open a video in a standard video player in Oculus Quest 3 from a script. I'm trying to open it in three ways, none of them work.
The first two methods work on PC without any problem.
Method3 from this plugin: https://github.com/Andy-Roger/UnityAndroidNativeFileOpener
Video: https://youtu.be/Qtk5pgVpxLc
C#:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;


public class VideoOpener : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OpenVideo1()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.OpenURL(Application.persistentDataPath + "/DroneAttack_360_TB_30sec.mp4");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(ex); }
    }

    public void OpenVideo2()
    {
        try
        {
            string pathTo = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/DroneAttack_360_TB_30sec.mp4");
            Process process = Process.Start(pathTo);
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(ex); }
    }

    public void OpenVideo3()
    {
        try
        {
            AndroidContentOpenerWrapper.OpenContent(Application.persistentDataPath + "/DroneAttack_360_TB_30sec.mp4");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void OpenGoogle()
    {
        Application.OpenURL("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}

Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider
  android:name="com.cartoontexas.andyr.unityplugin.UnitySSContentProvider"
  android:authorities="a_very_unique_name"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

I want my application to close or minimize and open the video in a standard video player
like on pc: https://youtu.be/T9cw3AqkZq0
